# Maven 3: Generate Javadoc for defined artifacts

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-3, maven-javadoc-plugin

I want to generate javadocs only for certain artifacts of my project from within a dedicated docs-project.

That means that I would like to have an independent project called "docs" for example. In the docs/pom.xml I would like to define the artifacts that should be included in the generated javadocs.

So far I learned that I have to generate a separate sources.jar for the projects I want to include. But I can't figure out how to go on from there.

For now I can only imagine two approaches:

1. Get the artifacts (sources.jar) I want to include, unpack them and somehow point the Javadoc plugin to the source directory.
2. Define the artifacts I am interested as dependency and use the "dependencySourceInclude" option of the javadoc-plugin. But I am not sure if this is usage as intended.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found a solution my self. It is a bit of a hack but it does work for me. I chose to go with my first idea:

> Get the artifacts (sources.jar) I want to include, unpack them and somehow point the javadoc plugin to the source directory.

This solution has four differents parts which I'll explain in more detail later:

1. Generate sources.jars in all artifacts I want to include
2. Unpack those sources.jars
3. Generate Javadoc by pointing the javadoc-plugin to the unpacked sources
4. Package the generated apidocs in a zip file

Now in more detail:

**1. Generate sources.jars in all artifacts I want to include**

To generate sources.jars you have to use the maven-sources-plugin as follows:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>bundle-sources</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

You have to do this in every project/module/artifact you want to include in your apidocs.

**2. Unpack those sources.jars**

In you pom.xml you use to generate the javadocs you have to add the following plugins to unpack the sources.jar files.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>unpack-artifact-sources</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId><!-- your artifact here --></artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/unpack_sources</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <!-- add more unpack-executions here -->
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

You can add as many unpack-execution-blocks as you like.

**3. Generate Javadoc by pointing the javadoc-plugin to the unpacked sources**

Now the tricky part. Letting the javadoc-plugin know where to look for the source files. The imported definition is the `<sourcepath>` definition. In this section we define the folder where we have unpacked the sources in step 2.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.7</version>
  <configuration>
    <sourcepath>${project.build.directory}/unpack_sources</sourcepath>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>javadoc</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

When you call `mvn clean install` at this point you will end up with a `site` folder inside your `target` folder. In this site folder you'll find your apidocs. But to make this build all shiny and stuff we want to assemble the apidocs into a zip archive.

**4. Package the generated apidocs in a zip file**

To assemble the docs you have to use the `maven-assembly-plugin` and a extra assembly-file.
First the plugin-defintion inside your pom:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>docs-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <configuration>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assemble.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

assemble.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly>
  <id>${project.build.finalName}</id>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>target/site/apidocs</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```