# How to generate Javadoc for Maven Dependencies

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have a maven project with the following POM snippet:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>Foo-Deploy</artifactId>
<name>Foo-Deploy</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<description>foobar</description>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>de.foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>some-api</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <classifier>doc</classifier>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The idea is to have a dependency defined in which some sources are (this is created successfully before). 
Now I want to run javadoc on exactly THIS dependency. When I call

```
mvn javadoc:jar -DincludeDependencySources=true -DdependencySourceIncludes=de.foo.bar:some-api:*:doc:zip
```

it fails with the message

> Not executing Javadoc as the project
>   is not a Java classpath-capable
>   package

what is wrong ? and would it work anyhow ?

or how can I generate javadoc from a specific dependency (assuming this project has more dependencies) ?

Thanks

Comment: OK... i changed the packaging to jar (it was pom) - and then the error does not occur again.  BUT - it doesnt do anything... maven says Successfull, but nothing is generated :(

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947215/maven-3-generate-javadoc-for-defined-artifacts is related

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To generate javadoc for dependent sources, a sequence of steps needs to be done.  These are outlined in [this link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/aggregate-dependency-sources.html).

Essentially you need to ensure that the source files of the dependency is generated/available and `<includeDependencySources>` parameter is enabled.