# deploy javadoc with maven to webdav-url and unpack

Tags: maven, deployment, javadoc, webdav

I need to deploy the javadoc of my project to a specified dav-url, named `https://<host>/javadoc/<project-name>/<version>/` and unpack there.

I got it unpack in a local filesystem using these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947215/maven-3-generate-javadoc-for-defined-artifacts).

But how can I do that for a dav-url? TIA!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to mount the remote webdav location as a local drive and then use the local filesystem process you linked to.

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately I cannot do this in cause of technical reasons.